# Maximum "divide" operations on an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, prime-factoring, number-theory

Given an array of `n` positive integers *a[1], a[2], ..., a[n]* and `m` good pairs of integers *(i<sub>1</sub>, j<sub>1</sub>), (i<sub>2</sub>, j<sub>2</sub>), ..., (i<sub>m</sub>, j<sub>m</sub>)* where *1 ≤ i<sub>k</sub> < j<sub>k</sub> ≤ n , 
n<=100 &  m<=100*

EDIT: Each good pair (ik, jk) meets the following conditions: ik + jk is an odd number and 1 ≤ ik < jk ≤ n.

In one operation you can perform a sequence of actions:
Take one of the good pairs *(i<sub>k</sub>, j<sub>k</sub>)* and some integer *v (v > 1)*, which divides both numbers *a[i<sub>k</sub>]* and *a[j<sub>k</sub>]* and *divide* both numbers by *v*.

Determine the *maximum* number of operations you can sequentially perform on the given array. Note that one pair may be used several times in the described operations.

**My approach :**

I began by first prime-factorizing each number of the array.
Given one good-pair *(ik,jk)* we can divide both numbers *A[ik]* and *A[jk]* by their common prime powers i.e if `A[ik]=2^5 * 3^4` and `A[jk]=2^3 * 3^7` then we can divid both of them by *2* a total of *3 times* and divide by *3* a total number of *4 times*. The number of operations increase by the minimum of the common prime powers i.e by *7*.

Total number of operations can then be taken as the sum over all common prime powers for all good pair given.

However my code *fails* for the following **test case**:

```
N=10 

M=9 

A[]=67108864 8 2 131072 268435456 256 16384 128 8 128 

Good Pairs :

4 9

5 10 

6 9 

9 10 

1 4 

3 8 

8 9 

1 2 

4 5
```

The array has each element as a different power of 2.

In terms of *power of 2*, array can be written as :

`B[]= 26 3 1 17 28 8 14 7 3 7       //A[i] = 2^B[i]`

Selecting each *good pair* and subtracting the common power of 2 , my answer progresses for each good pair as  :

```
26 3 1 14 28 8 14 7 0 7 ans 3

26 3 1 14 21 8 14 7 0 0 ans 10

26 3 1 14 21 8 14 7 0 0 ans 10

26 3 1 14 21 8 14 7 0 0 ans 10

12 3 1 0 21 8 14 7 0 0 ans 24

12 3 0 0 21 8 14 6 0 0 ans 25

12 3 0 0 21 8 14 6 0 0 ans 25

9 0 0 0 21 8 14 6 0 0 ans 28

9 0 0 0 21 8 14 6 0 0 ans 28
```

Processing each good pair, **my code gives the answer as 28**.

However the **correct answer is 31**. I need help in understanding how the output came to be 31 and the approach to solve this question.

PS: The problem is problem E of codeforces Div2 Round 284.

Link to the problem:
http://codeforces.com/contest/499/problem/E

Comment: I think the order of operations matters. Here's an example, a = [2, 4, 4, 2], and good pairs = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 3)]. If you applied the pairs in the given order, you will get 3 operations. However, If you applied (2, 3) first, you will only be able to do 2 operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved by finding a maximum [matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in the following graph. For each array value x, for each prime factor of x with multiplicity, make a new vertex. If x = 12, for example, then we create two 2 vertices and one 3 vertex. Make edges between pairs of vertices that correspond to the same prime factor of array values forming a good pair. For example, on the input

```
A  B  C  # array indexes
8 12 18  # array
A B      # good pairs
B C,
```

the graph has vertices

```
{A2a, A2b, A2c, B2a, B2b, B3, C2, C3a, C3b}
```

and edges

```
{{A2a, B2a}, {A2a, B2b}, {A2b, B2a}, {A2b, B2b}, {A2c, B2a}, {A2c, B2b},
 {B2a, C2}, {B2b, C2},
 {B3, C3a}, {B3, C3b}}.
```

The meaning of taking the edge `{A2c, B2a}`, for example, is that we divide the array entries labeled `A` and `B` by `2`. The order of operations does not matter.

Now, there are algorithms for finding a maximum general matching, but they're complicated, and I was surprised that a programming contest would feature them. As it turns out, you've left out an important constraint, namely, that the good pairs sum to odd numbers, which guarantees that the graph will be bipartite and hence amenable to simpler algorithms. Depending on what the instances look like, it may be profitable also to switch from bipartite matching to maximum flow, which allows, for example, the five vertices and six edges for the `2` factors of `A` and `B` to be replaced by two vertices and one edge with three units of capacity.

Comment: Sorry. Actually the only reason I did not add that part of the sum of indexes being odd was because I thought it did not matter.
My mistake. 
I understood the creation of the graph but how does the good-pairs summing to odd numbers ensure the graph will be bi-partite?

Comment: @user3918495 If `i, j` and `i, k` and `j, k` all were good pairs, then `i + j` and `i + k` and `j + k` all would be odd, as would their sum, `i + j + i + k + j + k = 2 (i + j + k)`, which is a contradiction. This argument generalizes to all odd cycles.

Comment: @user3918495 A less silly proof is to put the even indices in one part and the odd indices in the other.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that you need to do some backtracking. How are you selecting your "good pairs"? What happens if you do not select the sequence of "good pairs" that allows the longest possible substitution chain?

You can consider the initial array as a "state":

```
// using JSON notation; in C use structs, in Java use classes...
initialState = {
   numbers: [67108864 8 2 131072 268435456 256 16384 128 8 128],
   pairs: [[9, 4], [5,10], [6,9], [9, 10]], // several missing
   depth: 0
}
```

You can then attempt to perform one of `pairs.length` substitutions to advance to "child" states (where you divide the chosen numbers by a common factor, and increment the "depth" conuter); but it is possible that performing one of these substitutions removes the posibility to perform another, different substitution: for example, I can pair 9 with 4, or with 10, or with 6... This means that it is, in general, possible to reach a "dead end" that is not the *deepest* dead end.

Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking to find the correct answer. If it runs too slow, you can try some pruning: avoid visiting the same state more than once, by keeping track of unique arrays of numbers used.

Comment: Good pairs are given as input.

It is a question from codeforces site.
What I don't understand is why the answer is not 28 and actually 31.

http://codeforces.com/contest/499/problem/E

Comment: Because you are using the pairs in a non-optimal order. Follow the wikipedia link

Comment: Thanks. 
I read the wiki link.
Can you explain the optimal order for this case only and how you got it.
How you would apply backtracking to it?